# Scratch workspace for ArcGIS Desktop: file name conflict for multiple users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, scratch-workspace

I have installed ArcGIS Desktop on a server (it is not ArcGIS Server installation) where I want to give access to users to use toolbar (developed using Python-Addins) that I have developed. All intermediate files are written to a folder "C:/Temp" (I am not specifically writing those but only have specified scratch folder to be "C:/Temp"). If multiple users access it simultaneously, will there be a file naming conflict inside "C:/Temp"? If yes, is there any solution to it (how do I make file names unique even if multiple users are doing the same process or running same function at a moment)?

Comment: You probably want to create a scratch folder by concatenating a username to a parent directory.  The target filesystem should have the necessary space (and ideally not be a networked drive).

Comment: I saved scratch workspace for *.mxd. Each user clicks this *.mxd to start the session and all sessions are therefore linked to same scratch folder but how do I save scratch folder by concentrating a username -- is it done in code or manually? [please spare my lack of understanding here]

Comment: Concurrent multi-user application design is different from single-user application design.  ArcGIS Server has tools to support this, but you need to actively manage this yourself outside the geoprocessing framework.

Comment: toolbar is developed using pythonaddins. ArcGIS 10.1 server supports pythonaddins?